# Store data from two forms

Tags: html, sql, flask

I have two html pages for registration, first contains Personal Details and second contains contact details. I need to get data from first and second page and store it in database.

```
app.py - https://pastebin.com/d9Jbx9VL

preg1 - https://pastebin.com/qcPpUN5s

preg2 - https://pastebin.com/Kppcr8sN
```

The methods to check in app.py are /p_reg1 and /p_reg2

After clicking the 'Next' button in first page,the data is shown in the address bar. But after submitting it in the second page, data from first page is inserted as 'NONE' to database.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yikjY.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**you taged sql.**
sql solution is :

you should create a view in database for inner join between Personal Details and contact details by Common ID.

**for example :**

```
create view vw_myview
select p.name, p.f_name, c.phone_num1, c.phone_num2
from Personal p inner join contact c on contact.id=Personal.id
```

Other methods are also available.
Explain more.

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: Do you know about database? You should create a view in data base, then call that in your source code. Other why without database, is javascript and etc